# The click function reacting wrong

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, click

I have four options and if someone pick one option and click on "nästa" the answer should be stored into a array. To make sure that the value has been stored I alerted the length of the array. But If I click on "Visa alla alternativ" and pick another question and once again click on the "nästa" the length will increase by one.

1. First attempt: The alert will show 1
2. Second attempt: The alert will show 1 and new window of alert will
   show 2.
3. third attempt: it will show 1 ,2 ,3.

Why is this happening?

Javascript:

var answer = [];

```
$(".option").on("click", click_question);

        function click_question() {


        $(".option").each(function() {
            $(this).fadeTo("slow", 0.1);
            $(this).off("click");
        });



        function store_asnwer() {
            $("#nästa").click(function () {
            answer.push(select); 
            alert(answer.length);

        });
        }

        $(this).fadeTo("slow", 1); 

        $("#nästa").fadeTo("slow", 1);
        $("#visa_alternativ").fadeTo("slow", 1);

        store_asnwer();

        return select = $(this).text();
        }

        $("#visa_alternativ").on("click", function () {
            $(".option").each(function() {
                $(this).fadeTo("slow", 1);
                $(this).on("click", click_question);
            });

            answer.splice(0,1);

            $(this).fadeTo("slow", 0.2);
        });
HTML: 


<div class="option" id="option_1"> Svars alternativ_1 </div>
<div class="option" id="option_2"> Svars alternativ_2 </div>                            <div class="option" id="option_3"> Svars alternativ_3 </div>
<div class="option" id="option_4"> Svars alternativ_4 </div>

<div class="question_nästa" id="nästa"> Nästa </div>
<div class="question_nästa" id="tillbaka_question"> Tillbaka </div>
<div class="question_nästa" id="visa_alternativ"> Visa alla alternativ </div>
```

Thanks for the help!

I would appreciate if I could get solution

Comment: That's generally what happens when you start adding event handlers inside event handlers and loops etc, a new event handler is added everytime, and it just keeps piling up.

Comment: post a fiddle easy to track mistake..

Comment: How can I avoid the handler to be added everytime as you said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are attaching a click event handler to `#nästa` at every click of an `.option` element, so the will be fired all. Attach the handler once. When you click an option store its value in a variable and ins it in the click function.

Code:

```
var answer = [];
var selected;

$(".option").on("click", click_question);

$("#nästa").click(function () {
    answer.push(selected);
    alert(answer.length);
});

function click_question() {

    $(".option").each(function () {
        $(this).fadeTo("slow", 0.1);
        $(this).off("click");
    });

    $(this).fadeTo("slow", 1);

    $("#nästa").fadeTo("slow", 1);
    $("#visa_alternativ").fadeTo("slow", 1);

    selected = $(this).text();
}

$("#visa_alternativ").on("click", function () {
    $(".option").each(function () {
        $(this).fadeTo("slow", 1);
        $(this).on("click", click_question);
    });

    answer.splice(0, 1);

    $(this).fadeTo("slow", 0.2);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/PDc7b/

Comment: Ohh, So I should not have put the "nästa".click function into the click_question()?

Comment: Nope, in this case you will attach a click handler at every option click and you'll face the issue

Comment: But I have changed the changes and it is working, but The reasons why I put "nästa".click inside the click_question was to make the "nästa" button only working, I mean clickable once we have chosen a option.. How to I make it so the click function is only working when the options is clicked?